# Fetch nearby location in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

I am trying to fetch near by location in my app but i am not able to get response from hitting the url through google . Here i am sharing my code so please any one can help on this will be very helpful for me .

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;   
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;  

    String[] mPlaceType=null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;

    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner 
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnFind;

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());


        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Google Map
            mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

            // Setting click event lister for the find button
            btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   


                    int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];
                        Log.e("type",">>>>"+type);              

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                    sb.append("location="+28.5158732+","+77.37133510000001);
                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyBTcRYgv2gbFEPamHuVyjpRNhSJRVuZhm4");


                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());


                }
            });

        }       

    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();                

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();
                Log.e("data",">>>>"+data);

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }         


    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            

            // Clears all the existing markers 
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker. 
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);               

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);            

            }       

        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

here i am sharing my json parser class which will parse the data which is coming from  hitting the url

```
    import android.util.Log;

    public class PlaceJSONParser {

        /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
        public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

            JSONArray jPlaces = null;
            try {           
                /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
                jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
             * where each json object represent a place
             */
            return getPlaces(jPlaces);
        }


        private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
            int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
            Log.e("place count",">>>>>"+placesCount);
            List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> place = null;   

            /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
            for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
                try {
                    /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                    place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
                    placesList.add(place);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return placesList;
        }

        /** Parsing the Place JSON object */
        private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

            HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String placeName = "-NA-";
            String vicinity="-NA-";
            String latitude="";
            String longitude="";


            try {
                // Extracting Place name, if available
                if(!jPlace.isNull("name")){
                    placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
                }

                // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
                if(!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")){
                    vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
                }   

                latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");            


                place.put("place_name", placeName);
                place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
                place.put("lat", latitude);
                place.put("lng", longitude);


            } catch (JSONException e) {         
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return place;
        }
    }
```

here i am sharing my xml file of main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"        
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
        android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />    

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

////////
here i am screen shot of the screen

[image: screen shot of the screen]

after clicking find button this response i get from url....

{   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 103.233.119.62, with empty referer",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Answer (score 1):

The code given is fine I had not used browser key in my main activity, If U have to get location using google api u have to enable **Google Places API Web Service** and You have to get **android key** and **servery key** for particular id from google developer console and **use server key in main activity** and **android key in manifest.xml**